# Automatically expand the image in push notification of GCM android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I was successful to set image as below code

```
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
    this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Bitmap remote_picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg1);
    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notiStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();

    notiStyle.bigPicture(remote_picture);
     PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, openIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
    .setContentTitle("Test")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(data_msg_sort))
    .setContentText("123")
    .setStyle(notiStyle);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

However, I need to scroll down the notification message to expand and see the image. Otherwise, it does not show in the notification. Could you look at my code and give me some way to set the image automatic expand with full size as below figure
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that if there exists any notification messages in notification area with higher priority, then your notification will not be displayed in expanded mode.

So you have to set the priority to `notification.priority = Notification.PRIORITY_MAX` to make it at the highest one. Please mention if you do that too, it may be collapsed too if there exists any notification with MAX priority there.